# Chai should overwrites my own property

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, chai

I have run into foolish situation. I am working with `elasticsearch.js` and generating some query objects in code. One of **Elasticsearch** queries is `boolQuery`, which has `should` property. And when I want to test my query object and write something like this:

```
 expect(result.filterQuery.bool.should).to.have.length(2);
```

I am getting an error, because my `should` property is overwritten by **Chai**. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `chai.expect`, you don't have to call `chai.should()`.

Comment: In the sample  code `should` is the property of my own object. I want to test this `should` property (it must be an array with two elements). And I can not rename it.

Comment: @Stalso I understand, but what I'm trying to say is that Chai will not overwrite the `should` property unless you explicitly call `chai.should()` somewhere in your code (either that, or you're also using the [`should`](https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js) package). So if you stop doing that, Chai won't touch it. In that case, you won't be able to use "should" tests, but since it looks like you're using `expect`, I don't think that would be a problem.